# WPF application using wrong app.config

Tags: wpf, app-config

I have two application configuration files in my application directory.  One is named Test.config and the other is named MyApp.exe.config.

Test.config is similar to MyApp.exe.config with slight modifications.

If I execute MyApp.exe, it uses Test.config to run as certain aspects of the application is configured within these configuration files.  However, if I rename MyApp.exe.config to MyApp1.exe.config, the application will not start.

If I delete Test.config, application launches correctly using settings in MyApp.exe.config.  This is a .NET 3.5 WPF application.

Anyone run into this.

TIA.